# Django like admin site for Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I want admin site for Laravel 5.2. My requirements are:

- I will be able to include my existing models into admin site. I should be able to perform CRUD operations on all models.
- I have used multi-table inheritance in laravel model. My admin site should simulate this inheritance
- I have used laravel's inbuilt authentication. It should integrate with admin site.

I am searching for the right solution since many days. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

At this time there is no package like the fantastic built-in Django admin.

But if you still want to create an admin and do it the an easy way, you can use [this package to create the admin site](https://github.com/FrozenNode/Laravel-Administrator).